# How to put restriction on specific jenkins job when using Role-Based Strategy

Tags: jenkins

We are a small team.  Developers are also ops guys.  When I use the role based strategy, I have a role `devops` that allows all developers to create and run jobs.  However, there's also a `go-production` job, and I don't want all the developers to be able to run it.  I tried `project role`, but looks like if I give the role `devops` to developers, the `project role` does not take effect.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Global Roles override anything you specify in the Project Roles, that's why your `project role` doesn't take effect. I propose you to limit global `devops` role to have permissions only for reading and creating jobs, and then create new project role with permission to run/configure/delete jobs on the specific project (or projects).

For project roles there is useful **Pattern** field, that consists in a regular expression aimed at matching the full name (including the folder name, if you're using Cloudbees Folders Plugin) of the jobs which the role will apply to. For details see official [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin#RoleStrategyPlugin-Userguide).